# Accessibility in AngularJS (tabbing)

Tags: angularjs, accessibility

I'm working on a new feature of our current project and we're dealing with the accessibility.

So basically I have a modal that is being initialized or triggered on a directive. The modal contents are series of dynamic sections.

1. Product Info section
2. Product Detail listing section
3. New Listing section

[image]

Now as you see the structure above. When we use tab, it will automatically "tabbed" all input fields (including buttons, input fields, textarea, etc).

Other things to note is that the **New Listing Section** is hidden IF there is an/are existing list(s) inside the Product Listing section.

So if you "tab" on **Make New List** and then press Enter, the New Listing Section appears and immediately focused on the textfield of that section.

This should be the sequence of tabbing when the New Listing section is enabled.

[image]

ON the first occurrence, it will pass all elements inside the modal including the just-opened **New Listing section** (green sequence). So after tabbing on the Close button, it will start again from the Listings and SHOULD NOT SKIP the elements inside the New Listing section; but the problem is, it is skipping that said section and is just following the red sequence. It will only TAB that section once they hit the Enter button again on **Make New List** button.

Not sure why but should this be a normal behavior or it should not skip the already opened section's elements?

**THE MODAL**

```
    <div class="listing-modal modal fade in" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <button class="modal-close-button hidden-xs" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="modal-close-icon">Close</span>
                </button>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Product Info</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="details-container">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="image-container">
                                            <img />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="info-container">
                                            blah blah blah
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="listing-container">
                                    <div class="product-listing">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled list-a90-class">
                                            <li ng-repeat="(index, list) in listings" tabindex="0" class="list-item" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? getThisList(list.name): null">{{list.name}}</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="cta-container">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addtoExistingList(selectedList,info)">Add to this List</button>
                                            <label class="cta">
                                                <a tabindex="0" ng-click="newList();" href="">Make New List</a>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="new-listing" ng-class="!listings.length ? 'no-list' : ''" ng-show="!listings.length || enableNewListingSection">
                                    <ng-form name="myProductListing" action="">
                                        <div class="form-input">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="listName" ng-model="listName" placeholder="New info" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="cta-container">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="createNewList(listName)">Create List</button>
                                            <label class="cta">
                                                <a tabindex="0" ng-click="cancelList();" href="">Cancel</a>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </ng-form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've already implemented the tabindex for list and it's working fine.

The only problem I had right now is the tabbing on the New Listing section.

I tried adding:

tabindex, aria-hidden=false

but these don't work.

Is there any other way to achieve this result?

Comment: Can you share the full `HTML`?

Comment: @MarmaCinas updated my question with the entire code of the modal. Thanks!